# Clicked on element that has x-click with Python Selenium but it do not redirect

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape the url given below with python selenium.

https://www.rtilinks.com/?5b5483ba2d=OUhWbXlXOGY4cEE0VEtsK1pWSU5CdEJob0hiR0xFNjN2M252ZXlOWnp0RC9yaFpvN3ZNeW9SazlONWJSTWpvNGNpR0FwWUZwQWduaXdFY202bkcrUHAybkVDc0hMMk9EWFdweitsS0xHa0U9

**here is my code**

```
from pprint import pprint
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from PIL import Image
import requests
from time import sleep
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)

wd.get("https://www.rtilinks.com/?5b5483ba2d=OUhWbXlXOGY4cEE0VEtsK1pWSU5CdEJob0hiR0xFNjN2M252ZXlOWnp0RC9yaFpvN3ZNeW9SazlONWJSTWpvNGNpR0FwWUZwQWduaXdFY202bkcrUHAybkVDc0hMMk9EWFdweitsS0xHa0U9
")

WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "soralink-human-verif-main"))).click()

sleep(10)
WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@id='showlink' and @x-onclick]"))).click()
```

After running through this code I should be redirected to https://rareapk.com/finance/?n1p0ei2ng5yd3gz but It stuck at the same page.

The element, I am clicking is given below.

```html
<img class="spoint" id="showlink" x-onclick="changeLink()" src="https://eductin.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Download.png">
```

[Element Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQe6Z.png)

### What is my code doing?

- First it go to this [url](https://www.rtilinks.com/?5b5483ba2d=OUhWbXlXOGY4cEE0VEtsK1pWSU5CdEJob0hiR0xFNjN2M252ZXlOWnp0RC9yaFpvN3ZNeW9SazlONWJSTWpvNGNpR0FwWUZwQWduaXdFY202bkcrUHAybkVDc0hMMk9EWFdweitsS0xHa0U9)
- Then click to `I'M NOT A ROBOT`.
- After that next page is loaded and selenium waits for 10 seconds.
- Then an Image (having text `DOWNLOAD RTI`) is clicked which should redirect it to [REDIRECTED URL](https://rareapk.com/finance/?n1p0ei2ng5yd3gz)

*But in the last step it stuck at the same url, it do not redirect*

### I have tried the following ways

- `WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@id='showlink' and @x-onclick]"))).click()`
- `wd.find_element(By.ID, "showlink").click()`

Comment: maybe first run without `'--headless'` to see what browser is doing

Comment: don't you get any error message when you run it in console/terminal? always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: I didn't test it with Chrome but Firefox (without `headless`) and browser first displays message to accept cookies - and this blocks access to button `I'M NOT A ROBOT.` and selenium can't click it.

Comment: I have clicked I'M NOT ROBOT button. The problem is DOWNLOAD RTI button.

Comment: maybe when you want to click `DOWNLOAD RTI` it displays other message which hides this button. Did you run without `--headless` to see what browser is doing?

Comment: I tested code without `headless` in `Chromium` and browser displays expected page but `wd.current_url` still show old URL (and `wd.title` also show old title). But browser shows redirected page in new tab and maybe this is the problem. How did you check if you get correct page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested code without `headless` and I see browser opens expected page but `wd.current_url` still show old URL (and `wd.title` also show old title)

All problem can be because page opens new URL in new `tab` and it needs to use `wd.switch_to_window(...)` to access other `tab`.

This code uses `switch_to_window(...)` and it shows correct URL (and title) in other `tab`.

BTW: I had to add `"Consent"` because my browser sometimes show it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from time import sleep

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager, ChromeType
#from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

#wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
wd = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()), options=chrome_options)
#wd = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

wd.get("https://www.rtilinks.com/?5b5483ba2d=OUhWbXlXOGY4cEE0VEtsK1pWSU5CdEJob0hiR0xFNjN2M252ZXlOWnp0RC9yaFpvN3ZNeW9SazlONWJSTWpvNGNpR0FwWUZwQWduaXdFY202bkcrUHAybkVDc0hMMk9EWFdweitsS0xHa0U9")

p = wd.current_window_handle
print('current_window_handle:', p)

try:
    print('Waiting for: "Consent"')
    WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Consent']"))).click()
except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception:', ex)
    
print('Waiting for: "I\'m not a robot"')
WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "soralink-human-verif-main"))).click()

print('Waiting for: "Download (RTI)"')
WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@id='showlink' and @x-onclick]"))).click()

print('--- active tab ---')
print('current_window_handle:', p)
print('current_url:', wd.current_url)
print('title:', wd.title)

print('--- other tabs ---')
chwd = wd.window_handles

for w in chwd:
    #switch focus to child window
    if w != p:
        wd.switch_to.window(w)
        print('current_window_handle:', w)
        print('current_url:', wd.current_url)
        print('title:', wd.title)
        print('---')
        
wd.close()
```

Result:

```
Waiting for: "Consent"
Waiting for: "I'm not a robot"
Waiting for: "Download (RTI)"
--- active tab ---
current_window_handle: CDwindow-31FDEC2C62AA0666A8F3A1DD2133D02C
current_url: https://eductin.com/how-to-fix-and-restore-deleted-mac-system-files/
title: How to fix and Restore deleted Mac system files. – Eductin
--- other tabs ---
current_window_handle: CDwindow-CB1EAE5B6DCD4ACF5D061ED4ECC314CD
current_url: https://sakarnewz.com/
title: SakarNewz – BOOST YOUR KNOWLEDGE WITH TECH NEWS AND UPDATES
---
```

---

**EDIT:**

Sometimes this code has problem to display information about other tabs because it seems tab runs all time JavaScript and probably Selenium can't access data.